# Posting specific, enduring to figure fix, issues with Javascript code

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a bug in my game. And I am concerned about posting it due to the least amount of code I have to give is very large and that might not even be the correct block of code. I am afraid of posting the question as it is also very specific to MY problem and most likely not relevant to other users seeking information.

Now my question is, can I post this on Stack Overflow? If not, where do I post it?

Also I'm not even sure if this is the right place to post it either so I am very sorry if I post it in the wrong place.

---

Inequality while comparing arrays? (Extra unwanted code being activated)

I have an issue in my game where the 'blue team' or more specifically `mobsBlue` Is getting some kind of advantage in the 'killing or attacking' part of my code.

what I need is so that when I play my game, and both 'teams' come out (rect objects that move towards each other) They equally annihilate each other if they' same amount of objects in both arrays

video in a sec

I have not got a JavaScript error.

Comment: This is the right place to ask for advice on posting a question. I do feel sorry seeing someone tag their own meta post about asking their own question with [low-quality-posts].

Comment: I'm not the best poster ._.

Comment: I'd say try not to be too disheartened. It is great that you are posting here to seek advice. If anything it shows that you're willing to improve. If you have a draft of your question, you can edit this post and add it.

Comment: Huge piece of advice: If you aren't sure you're at the right block of code for your error, try debugging some more. Throw in lines around your code to either log to console or alert what's going on. Step through your code and try to see what's happening where. Doing that might even help you figure out what your problem is and how to fix it. :) (Note: This advice from a newer programmer who uses this approach to solve Javascript/jQuery issues on a daily basis.)

Comment: Another bit of advice, though from the question asking side: "I" as a word should always be capitalized and never left as "i" in your question. The sole exception is if you're using "i" as a variable. Always start your sentence with capital letters as well. Try to be as grammatically correct as you can in your posts.

Comment: A sad day indeed if we've got people so anxious about asking questions that they feel they must first ask a meta question about whether or not they can ask their actual question.

Comment: google *"interactive step debugging JavaScript"*

Comment: @aroth - given the description that question will be closed or downvoted to oblivion pretty quickly and most rightly so as it sounds like it falls into multiple close reasons. If you do not even know what the problem is or can not articulate it you can not expect random internet denizens to be mind readers either.

Answer (score 19):

Thank you for posting here and not just directly assuming a code dump on Stack Overflow is a good choice. This alone makes me think you might have a chance at fixing your issue.

JavaScript can be a pain to debug if there is a small error in a large amount of code. It is client side and at first it seems like it has a mind of its own. What you need to do is install/open chrome, and use the debugging tools chrome offers. You will be able to set breakpoints from there and it will allow you to see local variable values during the execution of your scripts without using console or alerts which is important.

I too use javascript a lot. I have a gold badge in the tag. When I am having an issue I cannot solve the first thing that I do is make sure that I can reproduce it, which is arguably the hardest part of debugging not to mention asking on Stack Overflow. The first step is to open http://jsfiddle.net/ for me, and begin recreating everything needed to show the problem I am having.

Don't be mistaken, this can take a lot of time. Reproducing scenarios is not exactly always copy paste and often will require some developing just to make the environment in the test space work like your development space. Start with the whole thing, and then just trim it down as much as possible in the reproduction. Sometimes as you trim you will find the error.

Doing this pays off every time. Either you get to a point where you can reproduce the issue and identify the problem, or you get there and can very easily point others to it and let them work with it.

If you do manage to identify your problem in a reproducible off site tool like jsfiddle, make sure that you still include all of the code there in your post. While it is useful to include the off site tool, users still expect to see all of the code up front on Stack Overflow.

So basically, what you are doing is going to take time, and there are often not shortcuts to doing that properly. Code dumping on Stack Overflow is one avenue people do take to try to circumvent effort but they often end up getting question banned.

Take the time to reproduce your issue. It will either help you solve it on your own or will allow others to help you solve it on Stack Overflow in a constructive manner.

Comment: I don't think i can reproduce the issue... Its so specific and I don't even know the issue down to the core level. I have been debugging with console and alert to find a anomaly to the code level but have to at no avail.

Comment: @JammehCarr - What you have is a logical error. Which is where there is a flaw in the logic of your system. It is understandable that there is no error to show. However, you should be able to reproduce the values of the local variables during the situation that your logic dilemma occurs in. If that means that there are two arrays which each have a different set of objects then try to reproduce two arrays with separate objects, and then show where you are struggling to make a comparison or conclusion based on the state of those arrays or objects.

Comment: I really don't know how to do that with the relative complexity of my code like i'm still very knew and i haven't encountered a situation where i've had to fix code of this complexity.

Comment: Here is an interesting technique for cutting down the amount of code by writing a series of ever narrowing unit tests until you have simple failing test that exactly pinpoints the error in your code: http://threeriversinstitute.org/hitemhighhitemlow.html

Comment: @JammehCarr Travis proposed building a minimal version of your issue from the ground-up. This is usually the right technique for me, but when it's a lot of code, I find it more helpful to copy the project and remove code until the issue goes away. If you remove code that contains the issue, put it back, continuing to remove code until you only have a small piece of code with the issue. This tends to be very fast since you're throwing away the project anyway and can be as sloppy as you want.

Answer (score 7):

Good on you for posting here before adding your question.

Sorry if this is stuff you already know:

If you're getting an error in your JavaScript, that's a start. If you open your dev tools in the browser, with a bit of luck the console should log the error. If you click the link provided with the error, it should take you to the line of code that caused it.

When posting code, try to only take the relevant parts, so if the error occurred in a method, show that method, how it's called along with the data that was sent to it.

If you can track down the error via the console, you can add `debugger;` or a breakpoint on the line prior to the error, and with dev tools open, when you reload the page it should stop and allow you to inspect and step through the code.

If you're still stuck, post what you've learnt from your investigation. It helps if you detail what you've done to investigate and try to solve the issue.